# VBA Excel: How can I make one form change the position of another form?

Tags: forms, excel, vba

I have two forms, frmPE and frmCRE.  They are modal.

frmCRE has a button "Edit PE" that will open formPE (instance of frmPE).
If I don't play with the positions, formPE opens centered on top of frmCRE.
I would like to position them side by side so I can see both at once.

When I open frmPE, I can still see frmCRE but not touch it.  That's OK.

' This code is in cmdEditPE

```
Set formPE = New frmPE
Load formPE
If Not formPE.bInitialize(vbFalse) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR
Me.Left = 100  ' move frmCRE to the left so I can see it 
formPE.Left = Me.Left + Me.Width   ' move frmPE to move to the right side of frmCRE (bad)
formPE.Show
```

I think the problem is that when formPE opens, it uses its default left setting.  From within PE, I can see that me.Left = 0 even though it was set before the show.

Is there a way I can use the formPE.bInitialize routine to see that frmCRE is open and find out its LEFT and WIDTH so I can set formPE.Left correctly, or a way I can set it from frmCRE as I was trying to do above?

Thanks
Shari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Activae` event of `frmPE` to move itself, but only if `frmCRE` is visible.

In `frmPE`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    If frmCRE.Visible Then
        Me.Left = frmCRE.Left + frmCRE.Width
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!  It actually works even without the IF, so I took it out.  It would have taken me forever to figure out Activate event. Why does it work?

Comment: Glad it helped.  The reason I put the If in is so that if frmPE is opened _while frmCRE is closed_, frmPE is not moved.